# How can I force reload a CollectionViewCell's background image when its superframe's frame changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView whose frame changes when the keyboard is shown. As the CollectionViewCells and so the background image is fitted to the initial frame of the CollectionViewCell. When the keyboard is shown and the CollectionView's frame changes, I create a new CollectionViewFlowLayout which changes the frame of the CollectionViewCells, and as a result it cuts off the background.

Is there a way for me to reload the background image of the CollectionViewCells after their frame has been changed?

Comment: Can you can subclass the cells and override layoutSubviews? This also sounds like you can probably use auto layout and save yourself the trouble of setting frames yourself.

Comment: Yeah I've already tried that but the background still gets cropped off